# Notice: Undefined offset: 27 in Test.php on line 40

Tags: php, random

I wrote something like this in JS but now i want it in php and i have this problem, can you help me guys?

> server Notice: Undefined offset: 27 in Test.php on line 35

line 35 is: `array_push($pole2, $pole1[$ran]);`

```
$pole1 = array();
$pole2 = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
    array_push($pole1, $i + 1);
}
for ($i = 0; $i < 25; $i++) {
    $ran = floor(rand(1, 50));
    // echo $ran . " ";
    array_push($pole2, $pole1[$ran]);
    array_splice($pole1, 1);
}
```

I tried use this but it doesnt work:

```
if (!isset($pole2[$ran])) {
    $pole2[$ran] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Why you check `pole2` while notice is about `pole1`?

Comment: ou i am retard :D  I had not noticed, i tried repair all time something what was right, thank you

Comment: $pole1 = array();
        do {
            $number2 = rand(1, 50);
            if (!in_array($number2, $pole1))
                $pole1[] = $number2;
        } while (count($pole1) < 25);
        print_r($pole1);   I think its easier